# Problem when trying to run script

Tags: command-line

Есть проблема на Ubuntu 11.10, при запуске sh скриптов, без активной консоли, команда who не отображает активных пользователей, а в скрипте необходимо знать, какой пользователь активен сейчас. Кто нибудь сталкивался?

(*Google Translate's courtesy*)

There is a problem on Ubuntu 11.10, when you run the sh script, without the active console, the team who does not show active users, but the script needs to know which user is active right now. Who ever came across?

---

By the way acpi package has a bug related to my problem, its script is also used by the command `who`.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep acpi | awk '{print $2 "_" $3}'
acpi_1.5-3ubuntu1
acpi-support_0.138
acpid_1:2.0.10-1ubuntu2.3

$ grep who /usr/share/acpi-support/*
/usr/share/acpi-support/power-funcs: user=$(who | awk "/:$displaynum)/ { print \$1; exit }")
/usr/share/acpi-support/power-funcs: user=$(who | awk "/:$displaynum/ { print \$1; exit }")
```

I think this can be fixed:

```
user=$(users | sed 's | |\n|g' | uniq)
```

***_*__*_*** Updated 12.01.2012
The problem is not solved!
Small amusing experiment:
for the test with `who` and `user` commands, I run the terminal, and add the following lines to /etc/crontab:

```
* * * * *   root    echo 'who: '`who` >> /123
* * * * *   root    echo 'users: '`users` >> /123
* * * * *   root    echo 'users /var/run/utmp: '`users /var/run/utmp` >> /123
* * * * *   root    echo 'users /var/log/wtmp: '`users /var/log/wtmp` >> /123
```

And check the /123 file when terminal is running:

```
users /var/log/wtmp: administrator administrator...
who: administrator pts/3 2012-01-12 14:59 (:0.0)
users: administrator
users /var/run/utmp: administrator
```

when  terminal is closed:

```
who: 
users: 
users /var/run/utmp: 
users /var/log/wtmp: administrator administrator ...
```

Again, the question of how to get a list of users logged on to the system (X session), from the console as root.

Until I see only one solution:

```
user=$(users /var/log/wtmp | sed 's| |\n|g' | uniq)`
```

Who knows a more elegant solution? Or is this just an option?
Or maybe it's still a bug?

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Please use English to get help from this community. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The currently logged-in user is set in the environment variable $USER

```
echo $USER
```

This should give you all you need. For a list of all users logged-in run

```
users
```

Comment: I need use in my script notify-send command, and run script as root, value $USER return root, but i need run notify-send as logged user with command:
`su user -l -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/notify-send -t 500 'text'"`

Comment: Takkat, thank a lot! `users` this is what I need! Sending notices to all users get this:<br/>
`#!/bin/sh for user in $(users): do
    su $user -l -c "DISPLAY=:0.0 /usr/bin/notify-send -t 500 'text'"
done`<br/>
p.s. Sorry for my english

Comment: By default, the program `users` reads data from ***/var/run/utmp***
but there is no relevant information and program `users` not show logged users... But if you specify the ***/var/log/wtmp***, then the program begins to provide data. Finnaly we get a construction: `users /var/log/wtmp | sed 's| |\n|g' | uniq`